# SQL Server Management Studio Registered Servers Network location

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a way to change the location of the SQL Management Studio 2005 Registered Servers?
We want to use the same registered servers inside our team, so it would be great to point to a network location, so after changing a server it will automatically be visible to other team members. The export / import functionality still needs manual steps to get an update of the server list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any way to share the same registration set on multiple computers.  But maybe this can help:

http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3587206/Drilling-Into-SQL-Server-Management-Studio.htm